# How to make a villager trading capsule in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a villager trading capsule in Minecraft. To make sure the villager can’t escape, I added a 2 high opening for the capsule, and then added a trapdoor on the roof. It worked and the villager can’t escape. But the issue is, I'm unable to place the villager’s job block under the trap door, not because the trapdoor is disrupting it, but it appears that the villager is standing on the block I’m trying to place on. Check image below for clarification.[image]
I think it is because of the trapdoor, and I tried changing to slabs but it did not look aesthetically pleasing AT ALL. We could barely see the villager! So I’m reluctant to switch from trapdoor, so please recommend an alternative.
And P.S: I’m on Minecraft Pocket Edition, but I use Xbox controllers.

Comment: Prehaps you could temporarily give the villagers an extra block of space in the back of the room, use a bucket of water to push it to the back then remove the water afterwards, place the villager's workplace block where you were trying to put it before, then remove that extra block of space in the back to give the room its original size.  Though in the end, you may want to give the villager's room some light, as in worse-case scenario a zombie could spawn in there.

Comment: Also you tagged this post as Java Edition, but from the coordinates on the top left screen, to the Xbox One controller inputs at the bottom of the screen, I'm quite sure that what you're actually playing on is Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

The first question to ask is, what console or computer and what version you are playing on. On PC, you can use a trapdoor to get into swimming or Elytra form and go through one gap spaces. I believe if you are on PC and have 1.14 or after you can do that. My ideal idea is to make sure not to get a nitwit, and trap a few villagers under your one gap spaces by digging a extra block for one, and put down some stuff like compost, grinder, etc. for their jobs then trade away. Or make your own village for a chance to get a iron golem farm also!

Answer (score 0):

Try to crouch and push the villager into the correct spot, then he shouldn't move inside the trapdoor again. If you still can't place the workstation then place it while still in the capsule and use a pearl to get out. Hope this helps!